# Strange behavior when converting date

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working with a date string that looks like this

```
Wed Nov 30 22:51:20 +0000 2011
```

I'm trying to convert it to type Date in Actionscript. When I do this, I get the date in 1969.

```
asDate = new Date(asString); //or new Date(asString as String);
```

But if I create a class with static function that just does exactly the same thing, I get the real date in 2011.

```
asDate = MyDate.retDate(asString);

public class MyDate {
  public static function retDate(asString:String):Date {
     return new Date(asString);
  }
}
```

The class way works, but the simple way doesn't, even though what I'm doing in the class is exactly the same line as when I try to do it without the class. I thought maybe it has to do with the type, so I tried `new Date(asString as String);` but this also give the 1969 date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try parsing the date using the static function `Date::parse()`? For example:

```
var date:Date = Date.parse(asString);
```